# Issue while pinning query to dashboard in App Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, appinsights

I'm trying to pin a query result to AppInsights dashboard but the data is getting grouped in the background.
When I run the query by itself, the graph is showing up as expected but when I click "Pin to dashboard" and view the same in dashboard, it only shows completely different data.

[image]

After pinned to dashboard

[image]
Before pinning to dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized it was because in Azure app insights dashboard, pinned charts are limited to 30 days of data, regardless of what is specified in the query or the tile configuration

Comment: I missed this info. And for others who have the same issue, please refer to this [official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/overview-dashboard#troubleshooting).

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Op is correct. For application insights dashboard, it will only display the data within 31 days. The official link is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/overview-dashboard#troubleshooting).

---

This may due to you're not selecting a proper `start-time` and `end-time` for the dashboard.

Try to select a proper start-time and end-time in the dashboard, a screenshot as below:

[image]

And if the issue still occurs, please share us your query code, and other dashboard settings.

Comment: Realized it was because in Azure app insights dashboard, pinned charts are limited to 30 days of data, regardless of what is specified in the query or the tile configuration.

Comment: @mrnair, change the start time and end time does not work for you?

Comment: No, as the time range was greater than 30 days.

Comment: @mrnair, I found that [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/overview-dashboard#troubleshooting
). But the maximum day is 31, not 30:)